# how to create a bootable Wndows 10 USB installer on my MBP 2017 without being asked to repartition my drive?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

as title.

On my MBP2010 (which is currenty 1000s miles away), I don't get the option to repartition my drive. I just get the option to create the USB installer + download bootcamp drivers.

With the 2017 MBP, it wants to repartition the internal SSD which is not something I want to do.

Thanks!

[image]

**After pressing Continue, I get this**

[image]

Comment: *"...With the 2017 MBP, it wants to repartition my drive..."* - In this sentence, are you talking about an external drive (like a USB Flash Drive) or your internal drive?

Comment: @pixelomer internal